# Why use clone() of ReLU in torch's inception net?

Tags: clone, torch

I'm reading https://github.com/Element-Research/dpnn/blob/master/Inception.lua

You can see tons of `clone()`'s in this source. like

```
mlp:add(self.transfer:clone())
```

`self.transfer` is nothing more than `nn.ReLU()`.

Then,

1. Why does this code call activation functions using `clone()`? Does this only concern memory issues?
2. I thought that the `clone` shares parameters. Is this right? If it's right, it means all activations of this inception module share parameters. It looks like nonsense. Do I misunderstand Inception-Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you don't clone the module `self.transfer` then all modules `transfer` in your net `mlp` will have the same state variables `output` and `gradInput`.

Look for example at this toy code

```
require 'nn'

module = nn.ReLU()

net = nn.Sequential():add(nn.Linear(2,2)):add(module):add(nn.Linear(2,1)):add(module)

input = torch.Tensor(2,2):random()
net:forward(input)

print(net:get(2).output)
print(net:get(4).output)
```

Both print statements will return the same value. Modifying one of the `module` outputs will modify the other one. Since we do not want this behavior we have to clone the module. (However in your case, cloning a simple `nn.ReLU()` is not that useful.)

2. The documentation says

   > If arguments are provided to the clone(...) function it also calls share(...) with those arguments on the cloned module after creating it, hence making a deep copy of this module with some shared parameters.

Therefore if you don't provide any arguments the parameters won't be shared.